# I want to extract all substring that match regex pattern from a String and store them in a String array

Tags: java, arrays, regex, string

I want to extract all the substrings that have Exceptions. For example, "SQLException", "SQLSyntaxErrorException" etc from the below string, and store those values in a String array. How do I go about it? I tried to use the split(regex) method but that stores everything else in  the array but not those exceptions. Help is appreciated.

```
public static void exceptionsOutOfString(){
    String input = "org.hibernate.exception.SQLException: error executing work org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: error \n" +
            "executing work &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;at  ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final] &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;\n" +
            "\\norg.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: error executing work &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;at  ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final] \n" +
            "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: malformed string: 'Acme''&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;at";

    String regex = ".[a-zA-Z]*Exception";

    String[] exceptions  = input.split(regex);
```

Comment: Please show exactly what strings you expect to capture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
String input = <exception list...>
String regex = "\\w+Exception";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(input);

while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Prints

```
SQLException
SQLGrammarException
SQLGrammarException
SQLSyntaxErrorException
```

To put them in an array, do the following:

```
String[] array = m.results()
             .map(MatchResult::group)
             .toArray(String[]::new);
```

`m.results()` produces a `stream` of `MatchResults`.  So take that and use the `group` method to get the string then return an array.

As was astutely observed by [Abra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2164365/abra), the above was not introduced until release JDK 9.

Here is an alternative.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
while (m.find()) {
     list.add(m.group());
}
```

Then either use as a list or convert.

```
String[] array = list.stream().toArray(String[]::new);
// or
String[] array = list.toArray(String[]::new); // JDK 11
```

Comment: Thanks. How do i put the results of the matcher in a String[] array?

Comment: Perhaps you should mention that method `results()` was added to class `Matcher` in JDK 9?

Comment: Thanks @WJS  that works. Thanks for  your help!! I was asked this question and the guy had a one line solution for extracting the regex matches from the string and store them in an array. I just can't remember what he did! :(